# unable to view All build definitions under Team explorer build option

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I am trying to check for my build definition under team explorer build option. I am not getting any options. It is blank.
[image]

Any idea how I can get my Build definitions.
I am working in VS 2013

Comment: Did this only occurs on your VS2013? What's the result of other fellow's VS for the same team project?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT .. Well, I am only checking with VS 2013, I don't have another versions but I don't think version of VS should be problem since I checked on another system in VS 2013 and I could see the required options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the same user account on another system in VS2013, this issue seems only related to your local VS 2013.

Try to  close the VS, [clear both TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/), then reopen it.